# Android, set WebView dimensions with px in Java

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo

Currently I am using the following to set height and width:

```
//landsapeWebView is a WebView, and deviceHeight and deviceHeight are ints
landsapeWebView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(deviceHeight, deviceWidth));
```

This seems to work fine on some devices but not others. The only conclusion I've come to is that this is setting the height and width like this:

```
<WebView  android:layout_width="(deviceWidth)dp"
          android:layout_height="(deviceHeight)dp" />
```

when what I want is this:

```
<WebView  android:layout_width="(deviceWidth)px"
          android:layout_height="(deviceHeight)px" />
```

How can I specify the unit of measure?

---

**Extra disclosure for @collusionbdbh**

```
    display      = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 1){
        deviceWidth  = display.getWidth();
        deviceHeight = display.getHeight();
    }else{
        deviceWidth  = display.getHeight();
        deviceHeight = display.getWidth();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I think your problem probably exists in where you are getting the device dimensions, can you add the code that does that?

Comment: Added. I should note that it works fine in api-15 phone emulator, and is breaking in galaxy tab api-8 emulator.

Comment: I think the phone emulator will always be in portrait mode (orientation = 0) so basically setting the height and width opposite is working because the you have height before width when you set up the layout parameters. The tab will be in landscape (orientation = 1) and I think that is causing the height and width to be in the incorrect places.

Comment: @collusionbdbh nah, I have that part figured out. Its specifying unit of measure I need to know.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not an orientation issue?

Regardless of the orientation of the device the width is the horizontal and the height is the vertical.

I would try this:

```
display      = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    deviceWidth  = display.getWidth();
    deviceHeight = display.getHeight();
```

I am pretty sure width should be before height:

```
landsapeWebView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(deviceHeight, deviceWidth));
```

should be:

```
landsapeWebView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(deviceWidth, deviceHeight));
```

Comment: how is that different than what I am doing?

Comment: sorry, hadn't seen your update when I posted that, just changed my answer.

Comment: no, the height and width are different depending on launch orientation, and this is a landscape view, so that order is correct.